# How to save the result output from cells containing a formula?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, copy, range

I have the following on Excel:

```
A = 1
B = 10
C = 11 (because there is a formula : A + B)
```

I would like to run scenarios, to do it I did:

```
Sub test()
Dim MyVar As Integer
Dim MyRes As Range
Dim MyDest As Range


With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set MyDest = .Range("A5")

For MyVar = 1 To 10
    Set MyRes = .Range("B3")
    .Range("B1") = MyVar
    MyRes.Copy Destination:=MyDest
    MyDest.Resize.Value = MyRes.Value
    Set MyDest = MyDest.Offset(1, 0)

Next MyVar

End With
End Sub
```

From this code I had a good result: I changed A value each loop, added B to A, take the result from the cell C and print them.

I have a 2 entrance dashboard: A / B with the corresponding value

```
 B 1 2 3 etc.
A   
1
2
3
etc.
```

and I want to run a scenario this time changing A and B and print the result in the corresponding cells.

Comment: OK so what's your question? Please be as specific as possible.

Comment: I would like to get A + B for each value of A and B .
In row : A 
In column : B 
The result in the corresponding cell crossing of A and B 
For exemple in the cell crossing A and B for A = 1 and B = 1 I want 2

Comment: Why not just use SUM formula?

Comment: Because I did a shortcut , in reality I've a big calculation dahsboard , when I changed the input A and B the dashboard give me a result and I would like to keep it for each value of A and B

Answer (score 0):

Say we have **2** worksheets, `model` with the formula and `result` to store the results.  Set up`result` like:

[image]

The **A1** values going across the first row and the **B1** values going down the first column.

We then run:

```
Sub whatever()
    Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    
    Set s1 = Sheets("result")
    Set s2 = Sheets("model")
    
    For i = 2 To 7
        s2.Range("A1").Value = s1.Cells(1, i).Value
        For j = 2 To 6
            s2.Range("B1").Value = s1.Cells(j, 1).Value
            s2.Calculate
            s1.Cells(j, i).Value = s2.Range("C1").Value
        Next j
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Afterwards, `result` will be like:

[image]

**Note(s):**

In general, if we have more than **2** input variables, it would be better to use a multi-column result rather than a 2-dimensional result.